# Adding the class was-validated not triggering bootstrap 4 validation

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make use of Bootstrap 4's new validation capability but I can't get the popover to show when I submit with a validation error.

My form is:

```
<form id="runModelForm" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="errCurrent" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">My label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm run-model-numeric" id="errCurrent" value="0.11" required />
        <div class="invalid-tooltip">Required</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
        <small class="form-text text-muted col-sm-12">Some text here</small>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

In a javascript file I reference using a script tag I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#runButton").click(function () {
    var form = $("#runModelForm");
    if (form[0].checkValidity() === false) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }

    form.addClass('was-validated');
  });
```

I am using Bootstrap 4.1.3 if it matters.

Comment: i inserted your code into a bootply fiddle and it seems to work: https://www.bootply.com/zGZytpEtvi#
Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: AH okay, so something is interfering with it somehow. It is not working at all for me within my app.

Comment: are u using the full bootstrap stylesheets or do you just import some parts of it? Maybe youre missing something there so it doent get displayed/styled properly?

Comment: I failed to mention that I am also using Kendo UI. It seems that by configuring my input as a kendoNumericTextBox, it modifies the control and Bootstrap validation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only validation being performed is if the field is empty or not. The "Required" popover appears if you blank the input.